# How to fix the reference line in react lightweight charts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to fix the reference line in react lightweight charts?

[image: How to convert unix timestamp to day, month, year in javascript?]

```
  useEffect(() => {
  if(chart && data) {
    const candleSeries = chart.addCandlestickSeries({
      upColor: COLORS.green,
      downColor: COLORS.red,
      borderDownColor: COLORS.red,
      borderUpColor: COLORS.green,
      wickDownColor: COLORS.red,
      wickUpColor: COLORS.green,
    });

                    
    candleSeries.setData(data || []);
       
  }
  }, [chart, data])
```

whenever there is a change in data the chart is getting updated, but the reference line it repeating as shown above. How can I prevent this?